# How to "lock" width in a TableRow

Tags: android, layout, tablerow

I have this (partly) layout:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/trLocation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/location"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="50dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="1234"
              android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
              android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</TableRow>
```

Now, when I make the data in `tvLovation` too long, it will "push" the `textView3` smaller and smaller, up until the text inside is even cropped, or flows to a next line if `maxLines` is not set.

How can I make sure the width of the first column is never smaller than my longest text?

Adding `ellipsize` to `tvLocation` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set textView3 and tvLocation's width to zero by set android:layout_width="0dp".

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. Apparently, `layout_width` has higher preference than `layout_weight` ? Do you perhaps have a reference to documentation about this?

Comment: read the method measureHorizontal() or measureVertical() in the source code of LinearLayout.
You will got it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use layout weight in a view, change it height or width to **0dp** depending on its orientation. Because when using the weights, the other attribute is ignored.

Here the views are aligned horizontally since it's in a table row and so change the `android:layout_width` to **0dp**